# Not able to print foobar in js only prints foo and bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

1. I am learning js
2. can you tell me whether the code is correct for below tasks...
3. I am able to print foo and bar
4. but not able to print foobar

http://jsfiddle.net/1u1o2es7/

```
// Looping from 1 to 100 print out the following
// If the number is divisible by 3, log X foo
// if the number is divisible by 5, log X bar
// If the number is divisible by 15, log X foobar
// Only one output per number
// Expected output:
//
// 1
// 2
// 3 foo
// 4
// 5 bar
// 6 foo
// ...
// 15 foobar
// ...
// 100 bar

for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
    console.log(i);
    //var str = "";
    if(i%3 == 0) {
        //str = "foo";
        console.log("foo");
    }
    else if(i%5 == 0) {
        console.log("bar");
    }
    else if(i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0) {
        console.log("foobar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is is because it is hitting your first condition, then the else if statements wont even get evaluated. :)

Comment: @TrentStewart can u update in my fiddle its confusing

Comment: check the order of your logic part.

Comment: @all is this correct http://jsfiddle.net/1u1o2es7/1/

Comment: aka [Fizz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)[Buzz](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting only "foo" at 15 is because `if (15%3 == 0)` evaluates to true and you don't go into any of the other cases.

move the `else if(i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0)` to the top if case.

```
for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
    console.log(i);

    if(i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0) {

        console.log("foobar");
    }
    else if(i%5 == 0) {
        console.log("bar");
    }
    else if(i%3 == 0) {
        console.log("foo");
    }
}
```

That's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can step through the compiler for javascript using your browsers developer tools. Just hit f12 and goto the Scripts section, you can set a break point and go through and see what the javascript engine is doing.

Comment: is this correct http://jsfiddle.net/1u1o2es7/1/